# Change color Text from CustomTextView

Tags: android, textview

By default to change textColor programatically is :

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

I need to have a custom Textview to change typeface and color by default, How can change textcolor from CustomTextView class, here is my code.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);




    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);


    }

public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {

    if(!isInEditMode()) {
        if (style == Typeface.BOLD) {
            super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf"));
        } else if(style == Typeface.ITALIC){  // constant used to set Lato-Light.
            super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Light.ttf"));
        }else {
            super.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is the way to set your default text color and typeface.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Lato-Light.ttf"));
    setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
}
```

The `init()` method gets called every time the text view gets created, and will then set the typeface and color in that. You can manipulate any other variables you want to in there.

Comment: Sideffect: This will also cause `android:textColor` attribute from XML to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTextColor(Color.RED);` after each super in each constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

In the /assets directory (not the /resource directory), create a folder called /fonts. Copy your custom font here. You can use both TTF and OTF fonts.

**Step 2**

In the /res/values folder, create a new file called attrs.xml. This is how the Android SDK lets you name custom properties for your widgets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="MyTextView">
<attr name="fontName" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**Step 3**

In /res/layouts, you will need to include your to-be-created custom text view in the activity_main.xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customfontdemo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Standard Android Font" />
    
     <com.authorwjf.customfontdemo.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        customfontdemo:fontName="pipe_dream.ttf"
        android:text="Custom Android Font" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 4**

In the /src folder, you will want to create your MyTextView class. It extends the standard text view, plucks the font name from the custom attribute, and applies the type face.

```
package com.authorwjf.customfontdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }
    
    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
        
    }
    
    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }
    
    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        setTextColor(Color.RED);
        if (attrs!=null) {
             TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyTextView);
             String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.MyTextView_fontName);
             if (fontName!=null) {
                 Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/"+fontName);
                 setTypeface(myTypeface);
             }
             a.recycle();
        }
    }

}
```

**Step 5**

Because the text view is now self-contained, you aren't required to make any modifications to our /src/MainAcitivity.java file.

```
package com.authorwjf.customfontdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```